# Moving of large MySQL database from limited resource server

Tags: mysql, database-backups

I have a `Windows Server` with MySQL Database Server installed.
Multiple databases exist among them, `database A` contains a huge table named 'tlog', size about 220gb.

I would like to move over `database A` to another server for backup purposes.

I know I can do SQL Dump or use MySQL Workbench/SQLyog to do table copy.

- But due to limited disk storage in server (less than 50gb) SQL Dump is not possible.
- The server is serving other works so basically the CPU & RAM is limited too. As a result, copy table without used up CPU & RAM is not possible.

Is there any other method that can do the moving of the huge `database A` over to another server please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few ways:

### Method 1

Dump and compress at the same time: `mysqldump ... | gzip > blah.sql.gz`

This method is good because chances are your database will be less than 50GB; as the database dump should be in ASCII; you're then compressing it on the fly.

### Method 2

You can use slave replication; this method will require a dump of the data.

### Method 3

You can also use `xtrabackup`.

### Method 4

You can shutdown the database, and `rsync` the data directory.

Note: You don't actually have to shutdown the database; you can however do multiple `rsync`s; and eventually nothing will change (unlikely if the database is busy; have to do during slow time); which means the database would have sync'd over.

I've had to do this method with fairly large PostgreSQL databases (1TB+). It takes a few `rsync`s: but, hey; it's the cost of 0 down time.

### Method 5

If you're in a virtual environment you could:

- Clone the disk image.
- If you're in AWS you could create an AMI.
- You could add another disk and just sync locally; then detach the disk, and re-attach to the new VM.

If you're worried about consuming resources during the dump or transfer you can use `ionice` and `renice` to limit the priority of the dump/transfer.

Comment: Hi Jersten, thanks for everything. It's a Windows Physical Server anyway. Sorry that I should make it clear at the first place.
Basically adding additional disk is not possible right now.

Comment: Anyway I did something using robocopy and able to copy over the whole database A folder in MySqlData folder to another server(Server 2). Now is the problem of attaching the single database at Server 2 which has MySQL running with some different databases.

Comment: Don't forget you can connect remotely with `mysqldump` which can be handy for extracting data from a server with limited resources.